# How come my table class has a top border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a `table-curved` class for Bootstrap tables to round the corners.

```
.table-curved {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.table-curved {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-left:0px;
}
.table-curved td, .table-curved th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table-curved th {
    border-top: none;
}
.table-curved th:first-child {
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 2px 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:only-child{
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 2px;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 0;
}


<table class="table table-curved " id="details">
</table>
```

But for some reason when I apply this, there is a thicker border up top.  Why?

Comment: Normally Inspect Element will show you where the style is coming from.

Comment: `border-collapse: separate;` makes borders to be displayed separately. You could either use `border-collapse: collapse;` or override the top border of `.table-curved` element by `border-top: 0`. **[DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/dipej/1/edit)**

Comment: @HashemQolami the top left border is 0px. Please take a look.

Comment: @TIMEX I modified **[the code](http://jsbin.com/dipej/2/edit)** in order to fix issues. Also added some comments to clear things up. Hope it helps.

Comment: @HashemQolami if you remove the <th> , then your version does not have rounded corners on the top.  I added the td:first-child on it

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`border-collapse: separate` is making your borders display separately. You are using two `borders`.

In `.table-curved`, you are using:

```
border: solid #ccc 1px;
```

In `.table-curved td, .table-curved th`, you are using:

```
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
```

**Solution:**

In `.table-curved`, override the current `border` property:

Add:

```
border-top:none;
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D64TZ/5/)**

Comment: This does not work with twitter bootstrap applied beforehand. The left top radius is 0px .

Comment: Can you post a link with bootstrap applied?